# Kotlin code to remove duplicate object of one particular type from mutable list

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I want to remove all duplicate objects of one type from a list.

For Eg.

```
 val models: MutableList<Model> = MutableList<DrawableModel>
 models.add(Student)
 models.add(Student)
 models.add(Teacher)
 models.add(Teacher)
 models.add(Teacher)
```

Expected Output:

```
Student
Student
Teacher
```

I want only one instance of a teacher on the list.

I tried with

```
models.distinctBy{ it is Teacher}
```

But it is applying distinct to the entire list not to a particular object and returns.

```
Student
Teacher
```

Comment: Why there are 2 `Srudent`s in the expected output? An item at index 0 is the same as the item on index 1.

Comment: @iknow yes my requirement is I want only one instance of Teacher and rest will remain same.

Comment: So You only want to have one `Teacher` in the list and all `Student`s stay?

Comment: @iknow yes only but models.distinctBy{ it is Teacher} is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a Boolean so it skips the first one it finds.

```
var first = true
models.removeAll { if (it is Teacher) (!first).also { first = false } else false }
```

If you want a new list, use `filterNot` instead of `removeAll`.

`distinctBy` doesn't work because it's converting the objects to distinct keys. Since you're key type is Boolean, there can only be two items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```kotlin
object Kotlin
{
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>)
    {
        val teacher = Teacher(0, "T1");
        val student = Student(1, "S1")

        val models = mutableListOf(teacher, teacher, student, student, student)
        
        // creating new list which is connection of two lists. First -> only Students. Second -> Distinct Teacher
        val newModels = models.filterIsInstance<Teacher>().distinct() + models.filterIsInstance<Student>()

        println(models) // [Teacher(ID=0, name=T1), Teacher(ID=0, name=T1), Student(ID=1, name=S1), Student(ID=1, name=S1)]
        println(newModels) // [Teacher(ID=0, name=T1), Student(ID=1, name=S1), Student(ID=1, name=S1)]
}

// classes like in the question.
open class Model(val id: Int)

data class Teacher(val ID: Int, val name: String) : Model(ID)

data class Student(val ID: Int, val name: String) : Model(ID)
```

So basically it is the main part:

```
val newModels = models.filterIsInstance<Teacher>().distinct() + models.filterIsInstance<Student>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list =  arrayListOf<Any>()
    list.add(Person("JAVA",20))
    list.add(Person("JAVA",20))
    list.add(Student("SQL",24))
    list.add(Student("SQL",24))
    list.add(Student("SQL",24))

    var filterList = arrayListOf<Any>()
    var studentCount = 0

    // filtering student object only 
    list.forEach {
        if (it is Student && studentCount == 0) {
            studentCount++
            filterList.add(it)
        } else if (it is Person) filterList.add(it)
    }
    filterList.stream().forEach { println(it) }// output : [JAVA,20],[JAVA,20],[SQL,24]
```